# JBoss Startup Problem

Tags: jboss, maven

While starting JBoss, it stops at Binding TransactionManager JNDI.

This is a clean install of JBoss on my machine and before installing it I had installed Oracle.
I thought there might be a port conflict so I changed the ports used by oracle to 9090.
Also I tried restarting my machine and running it again but it still didn't work.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?  Do you see any stacktrace in server log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a port monitoring application such as [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) and try to identify if there are any ports which are used for JNDI is bound to any other application. If found, terminate the application and probably your JBoss will start up without any issue.

If the problem persists, try to see and correct if there is any entities in your application which are wrongly mapped.

Comment: I tried using the port monitoring application but all the ports required by it were free.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this once, and it turned out that my AV software (Avast) was using a port that JBoss wanted. Once I sorted out the conflict, all was well.